# How can I return a Maybe<Single> in JavaRX coming from an Observable that could be empty

Tags: java, rx-java

Im trying to do something simple with JavaRx, even tho the methods exist, they dont work as I thought and Im a little stuck with it.

Basically, I have something equivalent to:

```
Observable<String> filteredNames = Single.just("Jack")
                .toObservable()
                .filter(it -> "John".equals(it));
```

A call to an API (that returns a Single type and later I make it an observable so I can filter it, based on that filter I could return a value or not.

The expected output its to have a Mayble

So, Ive done this:

```
filteredNames.singleElement();
```

But seems like there is an error, neither firstElement();

```
No converter found for return value of type: class io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleMaybe.
```

I tried also

```
Maybe.just(filteredNames);
```

But its not possible since filteredNames has an Observable and not a String... Any idea how to do this?

I use JavaRx 2

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows the problem you have. Using `singleElement()` and `blockingGet()` works fine to get the value (or `null`), there is no exception about a missing converter.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to transform the `Single` to an `Observable` in order to filter it.

`Single` already supports the `filter` operator:

```
Maybe<String> m = Single.just("Jack")
    .filter(it -> "John".equals(it));
```

The error is a hint that you are returning the `Observable` as a result being serialized / or converted which I would assume being a API endpoint.
If this shows to be the case, make sure to return the framework supported type, e.g. for a *Spring Webflux* endpoint, you would return a `Mono`:

```
return Mono.from(Single.just("Jack").filter(it -> "John".equals(it)).toFlowable());
```